# Using two threads with the same object to write to two different filedescriptors?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I have a class with a member pointer to an Object which has member function that uses system calls to write to filedescriptors. 
I want to expand it using threads, so I can write to two filedescriptors at the same time (they're not on a disc).
Is this even possible when the two threads are using the same object's write function?

```
int main()
{
 Writer oWr;
 myClass omyClass(&oWr);
 unsigned char data[10] ={0} ;
 int fd1 = open(...);
 int fd2 = open(...);

 omyClass.write(fd1, data, 10);

 //Create 2 threads using omyClass but with fd1 and fd2


}


class myClass
{
  myClass::myClass( Writer *pWr) : pWriter(pWr)
  {}

  void write(int fd, void* data, int size)
  {
     pWriter->writeraw(fd, data, size);
  }

private:

  Writer *pWriter;
};


class Writer
{

 int writeraw(int fd, void* data, int size)
 {
  int ret = write(fd, data, size);
  return ret;
 }
};
```

Comment: It is possible, but the result is not predictable if both threads happen to write to the same file object (kernel side). Use `pwrite`

Comment: No, each thread would write to a different filedescriptor. They connect to two usb endpoints, so there shouldn'd be a problem.

Comment: It's bad to ignore write return value like that...

Comment: It's just some example code to demonstrate. But thanks for pointing it out anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As a file descriptor is passed into the write function, there's no problem here.